# How to use Ember listView to lazy load filtered data?

Tags: javascript, listview, ember.js, ember-data

I recently found out about this:

http://emberjs.com/list-view/

Which is pretty amazing - as long as it can load from the Data Store. I'm relatively new to Ember, but I am currently implementing a searchBar component, which will be fetching results from the data store depending on a searchKey. I set up a model to make things easier, as I will be pulling from several different tables. For simplicity's sake, let's assume I only have to pull data from Users and Locations.

Now, the model i have set up is this:

```
App.SearchResult = DS.Model.extend({
    searchResultID: DS.attr('number'),
    entityID: DS.attr('number'),
    entityTypeID: DS.attr('number'),
    entityType: DS.attr('string'),
    resultText: DS.attr('string'),
    secondaryText: DS.attr('string'),

});
```

On the server side, I have a if block that determines what data to send as what. For example,

```
"SELECT userID as entityID,'user' as entityType, concat(firstName,' ', lastName) as resultText, email as secondaryText FROM users WHERE concat(firstName,' ', lastName) like ?"
```

would be the SQL equivalent for users.

Because I am essentially only getting searchResults, I don't want it to grab everything from the database (that matches the searchCriteria). Because we may have 100 John Smiths, I only want it to load the first ten Results on the first call. Then when the user scrolls through the div with the results and reaches the end, then it fetches and appends the next ten and so on. Think Facebook's friend search bar - the implementation front end is very similar. Posting that would make this a very long question.

However, the example shows static data, and I have not found any guide or such to use this Component to fetch data from the store - a fixed number of results at a time. I wonder if anyone could give an example of this? I have read that listView can do this, but I have yet to see an example that features the data itself.

To sum,

- How do I fetch data from the store, filtered by a parameter using Ember ListView
- How do I fetch this data ten records at a time?